# SQL Server : if column is not null show as a new row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
id  name  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
----------------------------------------------
1   user  b     c     e     f     g     Null
```

I want to display the results like this as col4 and col5 is not null but do not show col6 as it is null:

```
id  name  col1  col2  col3  col4  
----------------------------------
1   user  b     c     e     f          
1   user  b     c     e     g(from col5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT` for this. This automatically excludes `NULL`

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       ucol AS col4
FROM   YourTable
       UNPIVOT (x
               FOR ucol IN (col4,
                            col5,
                            col6)) u
```

Comment: Note for the lenght of the columns. _The type of column "ColumnName" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list._

Comment: @Sami - only if they are of different datatypes. In the absence of any `CREATE TABLE` there is no reason to assume they are

Answer (score 0):

With `UNION`:

```
SELECT id, name, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM tablename
UNION
SELECT id, name, col1, col2, col3, col5 FROM tablename
```

you can add to the 2nd select:

```
WHERE col5 IS NOT NULL
```

if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `cross apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (id, name, col1, col2, col3, col4),
             (id, name, col1, col2, col3, col5)
     ) v(id, name, col1, col2, col3, col4);
```

If you want to unpivot and explicitly exclude `null` values:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (id, name, col1, col2, col3, col4),
             (id, name, col1, col2, col3, col5),
             (id, name, col1, col2, col3, col6)
     ) v(id, name, col1, col2, col3, col4)
where col4 is not null;
```